# Installing python 3.5 or higher in a virtual environment on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, debian, wpa-supplicant

I am new to this, so apologize if the step is easy.
I have a Device which I am programming, which uses a raspberry pi (Debian). I have connected via SSH using PuTTY.

I wish to create a virtual environment, and test a program on the device to search the WiFi network SSIDs and pick them up. I found that a great package to use is wpa_supplicant.

However, here is the problem:
The device currently has Python 2.7.9 on it. When ever I create a virtual environment using python3, it creates a venv with python 3.4. Unfortunately, wpa_supplicantm requires python 3.5 or higher to work.

When I run sudo apt-get install python3-venv, I can see in the prompt that it automatically starts installing packages for python3.4.

Does anyone know how I can specify that I wish to install python 3.5 or 3.7?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Does it not have the python3.7 command?

I just checked a venv I have running on a 3b+ and it seems to have it.